# Is it possible to renew certificates for local environment using SIF or CLI?

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, sitecore-cli, certificate

As my **self-signed certificates** for `Sitecore 10.0` instance expired, I want to use `SIF` or `CLI` to renew them and best also to replace thumbprints to minimize manual work.

Is this possible with `SIF` or `CLI`?
Or is there any ps1 script I could use?

Answer (score 4):

Here is something similar you will find in the below thread where they have created a script that displays all the sites in IIS and you pick the one to update.

The script changes out the cert in the bindings and updates the thumbnails where needed in the config.

The script is too long so I am not adding this to this answer, You can download the file using the below link.

https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=66ab9a391be2c19038a46421b24bcbe4

Change the extension from `.txt` to `.ps1`

Hope this will solve your issue.